# How can I run filters in parallel in Lithium?

Tags: php, zend-framework, multicore, lithium, aop

[Lithium's](http://lithify.me/) [filter](http://lithify.me/docs/lithium/util/collection/Filters) has been implemented by chaining so parallel execution doesn't seem to be possible.

Is there a way to run filters in parallel by having the filters return promises as is done with [Dojo deferred](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojo/Deferred)?

Or is there another PHP framework with AOP functionality that can do this?

Comment: …and please, come talking that on the IRC channel irc://irc.freenode.net/#li3 - it'll be more interactive.

Comment: Ya, you're probably right. SO is probably not the right forum for this type of question. I'm moving away from ZF1 and before I learn a new framework, I want to make sure that it's design will be good for at least 3-4 years. Lithium, ZF2, Aura and Symfony are the top contender but none of them seem to address parallel execution which I think will be essential in the not too distant future. Thanks for your help and see you or /#li3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lithium's *filters* are enabling some kind of [monkeypatching](http://yoan.dosimple.ch/blog/2010/12/28/) which has nothing to do with deferring tasks.

Deferring tasks has to be done through other mechanisms like:

- [gearman](http://gearman.org/),
- [delayed job](https://github.com/seatgeek/djjob),
- [php-resque](https://github.com/chrisboulton/php-resque/),
- rabbitmq,
- zeromq,
- …

As PHP isn't threaded (under a normal configuration), nothing run in parallel.

Can you elaborate what kind of tasks would you like to run asynchronously?

Comment: Since filters can run independently, I should be able to run them in parallel for free but I can't with Lithium's current implementation because the filters are chained. How can I re-implement Lithium's filters so that they're not chained and then use Gearman to run them in parallel?

Comment: They cannot run independently. They are just like the WSGI middlewares onion skins metaphor: http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pylons-webframework/en/latest/concepts.html#wsgi-middleware What is your concrete problem? What are you trying to do?

Comment: As greut stated, PHP is usually not threaded. This means only one thing can execute at once, sequentially.